# Can someone sign a transaction and have someone else broadcast it and pay the transaction fees?

Tags: transactions, gas, signature, msg.sender

Can someone sign a transaction, maybe for sending funds or for smart contract interaction, and have someone else broadcast it and pay the transaction fees?

Or is it that the signer of the transaction also has to pay for that transaction?

Comment: Someone else broadcast it yes. Paying the fees no, at least not for simple native transactions, take a look at meta transactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically anyone can broadcast signed transactions, yes.

The signed transaction contains the gas price (and gas limit) that the sender is willing to pay to for getting the transaction included in a block.
Usually transactions with a gas price of 0 or below a certain threshold would get ignored by miners.

However, there are exceptions like [Flashbots Auction](https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/overview/), where bundles of transactions can be submitted to miners. If one of the transactions in the bundle yields enough reward for miners, they'd also include other transactions of that bundle, even if they have a gas price of 0.

Comment: Thanks. What I was really asking is: Can the person broadcasting the signed transaction pay for the gas? If no why not?

Comment: It's by design that the sender of a transaction has to pay the gas fee. I don't know if I can explain it any better, but broadcasting a signed transaction happens on a different level than paying blockchain fees. 
If you're looking for a workaround you might be interested in the Gas Station Network: https://docs.opengsn.org/#the-problem